# How to Turn string into bytes?

Tags: python-3.x

Using python3 and I've got a string which displayed as bytes

> strategyName=\xe7\x99\xbe\xe5\xba\xa6

I need to change it into readable chinese letter through decode

```
orig=b'strategyName=\xe7\x99\xbe\xe5\xba\xa6'
result=orig.decode('UTF-8')
print()
```

which shows like this and it is what I want

> strategyName=百度

But if I save it in another string,it works different

```
str0='strategyName=\xe7\x99\xbe\xe5\xba\xa6'
result_byte=str0.encode('UTF-8')
result_str=result_byte.decode('UTF-8')
print(result_str)
```

> strategyName=ç¾åº¦é£é©ç­ç¥

Please help me about why this happening,and how can I fix it.
Thanks a lot

Comment: You have a typo: `orig` is a bytes, while `str0` is a str. Add a `b` in front of the data for `str0` and decode it.

Comment: Put it another way `result_byte != orig` because the individual bytes in `orig` are combined to produce the Unicode characters, but each escape sequence in a string is a separate character already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is using a `str` literal when you're trying to store the UTF-8 encoded bytes of your string. You should just use the `bytes` literal, but if that `str` form is necessary, the correct approach is to `encode` in `latin-1` (which is a 1-1 converter for all ordinals below 256 to the matching byte value) to get the `bytes` with `utf-8` encoded data, then decode as `utf-8`:

```
str0 = 'strategyName=\xe7\x99\xbe\xe5\xba\xa6'
result_byte = str0.encode('latin-1')  # Only changed line
result_str = result_byte.decode('UTF-8')
print(result_str)
```

Of course, the other approach could be to just type the Unicode escapes you wanted in the first place instead of byte level escapes that correspond to a UTF-8 encoding:

```
result_str = 'strategyName=\u767e\u5ea6'
```

No rigmarole needed.

Comment: TIL about the deal with Latin-1. +1